# How to add 2 variables in the email body in win32com with Python?

Tags: python, email, win32com

I have this email template:

```
def email_tamplate(*args):
Format = { 'UNSPECIFIED' : 0, 'PLAIN' : 1, 'HTML' : 2, 'RTF'  : 3}
profile = "Outlook"
#session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
#session.Logon(profile)
mainMsg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mainMsg.To = "myemail@amazon.com"  
mainMsg.Subject = "Automated Crap Daily Update"
mainMsg.BodyFormat = Format['RTF']
mainMsg.HTMLBody = body2


mainMsg.Send()  #this line actually sends the email
```

And would like to send an email that has 2 tables in the body. So I have 2 bodies:
Here's one:

```
 eod = []
body2 = ['<html><body><table border="1" style="width:300px"><tr><td>Title Level</td></tr><tr><td>Source</td><td>Count</td></tr>']
header = [['Title Level']]

for row in cur:
    eod.append(row)


count=0
count2=0
for item in eod:
    body2[0]=body2[0]+"<tr><td>"+str(eod[count2][count])+"</td><td>"+str(eod[count2][count+1])+"</td></tr>"
    count2=count2+1

body2[0]=body2[0]+"</table></body></html>"
body2=body2[0]
globals().update(locals())
```

And here's the other:

```
eod = []
body = ['<html><body><table border="1" style="width:300px"><tr><td>Previous Day</td></tr><tr><td>Decision_Status</td><td>Count</td></tr>']
header = [['Prev Day']]

for row in cur:
    eod.append(row)



count=0
count2=0
for item in eod:
    body[0]=body[0]+"<tr><td>"+str(eod[count2][count])+"</td><td>"+str(eod[count2][count+1])+"</td></tr>"
    count2=count2+1

body[0]=body[0]+"</table></body></html>"
body=body[0]
globals().update(locals())
```

Both are created with data from different queries.
So I would like to be able to send in the body of the email variables body and boody2
Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just resolved the issue. It happens that I only needed to concatenate body + body2.

As simple as that. 
But thank you!

Comment: +1 Please accept your own answer or remove the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need for 2 bodies, use `.format()` and put unlimited number of variables into 1 body

Example:

```
text ='some text'
table= pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

msg.HTMLBody = '''<br>Hello, see this text: 
    <br>{text}<br>and this table:<br>{table}'''.format(text=text, table=table)
```